# How can we do mysqldump to another DB using php script such that triggers do not get dumped along with that?

Tags: php, mysql

How can we do mysqldump to another DB using php script such that triggers do not get dumped along with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$db_name = "db";
$outputfile = "/somewhere";
$new_db_name = 'newdb';

$cmd = 'mysqldump --skip-triggers %s > %s  2>&1';
$cmd = sprintf($cmd, escapeshellarg($db_name), escapeshellcmd($output_file));
exec($cmd, $output, $ret); 
if ($ret !=0 ) {
    //log error message in $output
}
```

Then to import:

```
$cmd = 'mysql --database=%s < %s 2>&1';
$cmd = sprintf($cmd, escapeshellarg($new_db_name), escapeshellcmd($output_file));
exec($cmd, $output, $ret); 
//etc.

unlink($outputfile);
```

Note that the new database will need to be created first. You will also probably need to specify a username and password to each command.

**edit**

You could also do this in one command e.g.

```
exec('mysqldump --skip-triggers sourcedb | mysql --database targetdb 2>&1', $output, $return);
```

Comment: I am using windows, will exec()  and sprintf($cmd, escapeshellarg($db_name), escapeshellcmd($output_file)) function will work here?

Comment: @OM The Eternity: Yes, I think so.

Comment: @OM The Eternity: yes, dumping to a file and then importing from it. you can use something like `tempnam()` to generate a temporary filename.

Comment: @TOM cant i do this without creating file? Cant I Just use the export Query?